# Is there any way to set background of images returned by google charts

Tags: google-visualization

Is there any way to make the background of the google charts transparent.
[Google charts.](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image_charts.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from the [google documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/chart_params.html#gcharts_solid_fills) on google chart API.

> Specify colors using a 6-character string of hexadecimal values, plus two optional transparency values, in the format RRGGBB[AA].
>
> For example:
>
> - FF0000 = Red
> - 00FF00 = Green
> - 0000FF = Blue
> - 000000 = Black
> - FFFFFF = White
>
> AA is an optional transparency value, where 00 is completely transparent and FF is completely opaque. For example:
>
> - 0000FFFF = Solid blue
> - 0000FF66 = Transparent blue